# Using variables from one class into another java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, web-applications, velocity

I have a java we application that is working with velocity. I get two variables in the first page via url that I extract using ureq.getParameter() method. One of the other classes that has a velocity container and I need to send one of the variables from the url to this velocity container. I tried creating an instance of the first class in the second class and using getVariable name method to do that but it did not work. Can someone tell me how I can do this?

Class 1:

```
package org.olat.dispatcher;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URLDecoder;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.olat.core.gui.UserRequest;

public class RemoteLoginformDispatcher implements Dispatcher {

    private static final String PARAM_newUrl = "ret";
    private static String newURL;

    @Override
    public void execute(
            final HttpServletRequest request, 
            final HttpServletResponse response, 
            final String uriPrefix) {

        UserRequest ureq = null;

        try {
            ureq = new UserRequest(uriPrefix, request, response);
            newURL = ureq.getParameter(PARAM_newUrl);
        } catch () {
        }

    }

    public String getURL(){
        return newURL;
    }

}
```

Class 2:

```
public class BaseChiefController extends DefaultChiefController implements ContentableChiefController {
    //Velocity container mainvc created here. It interacts with a html file. Removed the code that would not really matter

    //mainvc.contextPut("newURL", "something");
    //The below statement works. When I try with something, the something appears in the html file.
    mainvc.contextPut("newURL", myLogin.getURL());      

}
```

Comment: In *general*, we create an object of one class and pass its reference to another class via method parameters.

Comment: `velocityContainer.setVariable( theVariable )`, where `setVariable()` is a proper setter for the variable you are dealing with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create an instance of another class, simply create a "public CLASSNAME" method, and inside define all class variables with the "this" modfier. Then, call out the function you wish to use from that method, and when you want to use the class, just do "new CLASSNAME(args);"

Although, I am not really sure I am understanding your question.

Maybe this is your answer. You can use variables from one class to another class by making the variable static, then doing "CLASSNAME.VARIABLENAME = WHATEVER".

---

EDITED:

Okay, so as far as I can tell, you are using a method to return a static value from the class, which is much slower than just doing "newURL", RemoteLoginformDispatcher.newURL);.
Why not try this, as it is probably faster, and it should always work if newURL is defined. Otherwise, you have a different problem, and newURL is not being defined. If this is the case, try printing the caught Exception.

Comment: I am editing my question to include the code to make it more understandable. Sorry if it was not very clear.

Comment: I've edited the question to include relevant parts of the code.

Comment: Did this answer your question at all?

Comment: I am not sure what I am supposed to do over here. Is this what you mean:- declare the newURL as public in RemoteLoginFormDispatcher and use RemoteLoginFormDispatcher.newURL in class BasicChiefController?

Comment: Basically, yes. That is the same as using the method correct? And as far as I can tell, your problem is not the way your are getting the URL, but a problem with it not being defined. You should add a nullcheck, and debug.

Comment: It returns the value I put to check if it is null which means that it is returning a vlue of null when I call the method. I know the getParameter() method is working as my other parameters are being returned. They are being used in the same class(remoteLoginFormDispatcher). What mistake am I making that it is returning a null value?

Comment: I would try debugging to make sure ureq is not null, and I would also get the parameters and make sure that isn't null. If it is, you aren't getting the Parameter from the URL.

Comment: I tried getting parameter and displaying it and it is not null but when I call for that parameter from the second class, then I get a null value

Comment: I am not sure how but the program just started working. I don't think I made any changes that could have done it but I'll have to take a closer look. But Thanks a lot for all your help.

Comment: Thats interesting... No problem by the way!